# Devise - Where is the new.html.erb file located?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I just added users to my application using devise, and everything is working fine. But I can't see any folder of the type /views/users where I can change the new.html.erb and edit.html.erb to add new fields?

Does anyone know where these files would be located?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

run

```
rails generate devise:views
```

that will place the view files in the views directory

From the docs:

> Since Devise is an
>   engine, all its views are packaged
>   inside the gem. These views will help
>   you get started, but after sometime
>   you may want to change them. If this
>   is the case, you just need to invoke
>   the following generator, and it will
>   copy all views to your application: rails generate devise:views

Answer (score 0):

You should run `rails generate devise:views` task to generate views